# Check if string is empty in one line condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Can we check if like is empty in one ligne condition?
In some cases, it finds product_name but it is in a empty string.

```
productName = product['product_name'] if 'product_name' in product else 'Not found'
print(f"Product name is : {productName}")
```

I already tried some code like this:

```
productName = product['product_name'] if ('product_name', len(product['product_name'])>0) in product else 'Not found'
print(f"Product name is : {productName}")
```

Comment: Is product a dictionary?

Comment: Why does it need to be in one line? Two (three for the action based on your conditional I guess) very simple lines will accomplish what I think you want and be very readable. `productName = product.get('product_name', None); if productName is not None: print(f"Product name is : {productName}")`

Answer (score 4):

Use dictionary method `get` and or, sufficient would be just:

```
product_name = product.get("product_name") or "Not found"
```

Empty string and default `None` evaluates to False, so you end up with the second `or` argument, that is `"Not found"`

Presuming, of course, that product is a dictionary

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: Using the boolean operator `or` this way is not intuitive.  As long as you are using `get` just use its default parameter: `product_name = product.get("product_name", "Not found")`.

Comment: @rhurwitz Problem is with empty strings, as `get` ofc gives you that if that's in your dictionary, so you would have to handle it separately. `or` does it for you for both default `None` and eventually empty string.

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the question. Thanks for the clarification.